# Is it possible to run he typescript compiler in a child folder?

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a project with the following file structure

```
builds
-dev
--public
--private
-production
--public
--private

src
-server
-client

tsconfig
package.json
```

I'm using the parcel-bundler to compile and bundle the client folder. And I want to use the typescript compiler or tsc to compile the node js server folder. Is it possible to run the tsc from a specific directory?

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc (directory name goes here so the server directory) && parcel ./src/client/index.html --open --out-dir ./builds/development/public"
  }
```

**Root tsconfig**

```
 {
      "compilerOptions": {
        /* Basic Options */
        "target": "ES5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
        "lib": ["DOM", "ES2018"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        "allowJs": false,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
        "checkJs": false,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
        "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
        "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
        "declaration": true,

        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
        "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
        "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
        "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
        "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

        /* Additional Checks */
        "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

        /* Module Resolution Options */
        "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        // "paths": {
        //   "~*": ["./*"]
        // },
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      }
    }
```

**Server tsconfig**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../builds/development/private",
        "rootDir": "."
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) I think `-p` is the one you need

Comment: That does compile the entire serve project but it will still not output it in the correct outDir, any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Where does it output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing them bot with Parcel and the running them concurrently

```
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run watch-client\" \"npm run watch-server\" \"npm run serve\"",
"watch-client": "parcel ./src/client/index.html --open --out-dir ./builds/development/public",
"watch-server": "parcel ./src/server/index.ts --out-dir ./builds/development/private --target node",
"serve": "nodemon ./builds/development/private/index.js",
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a tsconfig that extends your root tsconfig and place it in the folder you want to build. In that tsconfig include the files inside that folder. Then specify that tsconfig in your script.

The specific `tsconfig.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../builds/development/private",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "./**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It works but it's ignoring the out dir from the tsconfig in the server folder that extends the tsconig in the root. "outDir": "../../builds/development/private" it just puts the js file in the server folder why is thin happening? I added the configs to the question

Comment: This is strange. I updated my answer with an example of a tsconfig. This works for me (difference being the include section and no "noEmit"). Also, full filename on extends.